# How to use easing with Jquery dialog widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-effects, jquery-easing

I'm using the jquery dialog widget in the jquery UI to show a form in a modal dialog. I would like to customize the animation, but I don't see anything in the options other than specifying the effect by name. For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: 'slide' });
```

I also noticed that the timing of the effect and the darkening of the screen (modal set to true) don't quite match when opening the dialogue. The dialog remains under the dark overlay until the effect is over.

Is there a way to customize the effect in the dialog options? Maybe use the easing plugin with it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can also specify other parameters providing an hash:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  show: {effect: "fadeIn", duration: 5000}
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dHs73/

Comment: This jsfiddle thing is awesome! Thank you